# Is Ubuntu 15.10 missing some files?

Tags: mount, live-usb, wubi, iso, 15.10

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and when I mounted the .ISO file I have folders and files like bellow:
[image]
then I compare to Ubuntu 15.04 ISO file which was mounted:
[image]

I tried to re-download Ubuntu 15.10 ISO twice to make sure there's no corrupted while downloading process, but it's the same.
Then I tried to use Ubuntu 15.10 without installing. After boot into live Ubuntu, I cannot perform anything. Then I discovered that all the apps were not installed. It's all empty even terminal.

What's wrong with that ISO file?

Comment: Your are simply missing **Wubi**. *Do you really need it?* See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1471344 OR http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice AND https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0MDY

Comment: Thanks, but how come it is missing and no apps was install  on live Ubuntu? Can you explain it to me? I guess I have to create a live USB bootable and try it once more time.

Comment: What do you mean with "All apps are not installed?"

Comment: When I search for the app, the result is all empty. Right click on desktop trying to open terminal and nothing appears. Although the apps' icons appear on launcher, but when I clicked on it nothing opens...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong or missing. `wubi` isn't supported anymore, so `wubi.exe` and `autorun.inf` are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I still cannot use Ubuntu without installing.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using Linux live usb creator to create a live bootable usb out of the ISO and then boot from the USB

Follow this
http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2014/11/how-to-create-bootable-usb-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thanks for your referral. I create live USB bootable many times and I'm sure that it's not the live USB that makes the bugs above.